# How to use a variable from a slot in another slot in QT

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am learning QT and have this problem. I have read some nearly similar questions here but the solutions are complicated to a newbie like me.

How can I access the value of `var_slot1` in this code?

Please help me to solve this. Many thanks !

```
MyProject::MyProject(QWidget *parent)
      : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    ..........
    ..........
    connect(ui.button1, SIGNAL(signal1()), this, SLOT(slot1()));
    connect(ui.button2, SIGNAL(signal2()), this, SLOT(slot2()));
}

void MyProject::slot1()
{
    int var_slot1 = 8;
}

void MyProject::slot2()
{
    int var_slot2 = var_slot1 + 2; 
}
```

Comment: Make `var_slot1` a member variable of `MyProject`

Comment: thanks a lot, Steve ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the value as a class member variable rather than as a function-local variable. Then you'll be able to access it from both member functions.

Comment: Don't forget to initalize it in the constructor in case slot2() is called before slot1().